# How to inject AWS account number into k8s ServiceAccount?

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, amazon-eks

Few weeks ago AWS announced "Fine-Grained IAM Roles for Service Accounts" for EKS.  It seems neat and now we'd love to make it work for our current deployments with Helm.  Applications are packaged in Helm charts, where all necessary resources for that  service are defined.  Application charts have no clue, by design, about where they run, either namespace or environment or even AWS account.  This makes charts very portable, installable in any namespace / cluster easily.  We store our secrets in Vault and at runtime the pod finds out environment specific info with:

```
- name: VAULT_AUTHBACKEND
  valueFrom:
    secretKeyRef:
      name: vaultinfo
      key: cluster
```

vaultinfo comes from another chart, that is setup when new namespace is setup.

Now for EKS to use IAM roles per pod I need to inject role ARN as value for 'eks.amazonaws.com/role-arn' annotation of a ServiceAccount.  This is my problem.  Name of role is not an issue, as can be figured out through naming convention.  Role AWS account however cannot be, and valueFrom only appears to be valid for Pod Spec.

Any ideas how to get AWS account into serviceaccount resource?
Serviceaccount resource must be owned by Helm chart and not modified by something else after installation.

Comment: I'm not familiar with Helm, but the API call for the STS service to [GetCallerIdentity](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/goto/WebAPI/sts-2011-06-15/GetCallerIdentity) returns an `Account` property. Perhaps that can be integrated into your process.

Comment: As far as I know Helm v2 and v3 render templates locally, so calling STS locally isn't going to return correct AWS account, nor should you even have AWS access to install a chart.

Comment: How were you handling the role before? can't you take the role from the values?

Comment: I didn't restrict aws perms per pod before, now I want to.  I can't take role from values because I don't want to define it values.  I keep chart templates and values in app repository.  I don't want my repository to know about k8s clusters or which AWS account it runs in.